I want to find the volume of a noncircular cylinder that lies inside r=1+$cos(\theta)$ and outside the circle r=1,and top of the cylinder lies on x=z.
First I think as since our $x=z$ then the volume of our right non-circular cylinder's volume is ,where R is the region we integrating and dA is the change in area,           $$ \int\int_RxdA   $$
Then I changed x with $(1+cos(\theta)).(cos(\theta))$ since r=1+cos($\theta$)         $$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{1+cos(\theta)} (1+cos(\theta))(cos(\theta))rdrd\theta
$$
When we integrate it we get ;
$$
\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} cos^4(\theta)+3cos^3(\theta)+2cos(\theta)d\theta
$$
After that i divided the integral in 3 parts as;
$$  
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}cos^4(\theta)d\theta + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}3cos^3(\theta)d\theta+\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi}2cos^2(\theta)d\theta
$$
Lastly, I applied integration by parts to the first one,and make the change $cos^2(\theta)=1-sin^2(\theta)$ in the second when and lastly i get;
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left[ cos^3(\theta)sin(\theta)-\frac{8}{3}(\frac{sin(4\theta)}{4}-\theta) \right]_0^{2\pi} +\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{}{}3sin(\theta)-sin^3(\theta)  \right]_0^{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2} 
\left[\frac{sin(2\pi)}{2}+\theta \right]_0^{2\pi}
$$
And then i find the answer as $\frac{22\pi}{3}$ which is not the answer, where did i do the mistake, boundaries or the integration?

Why not mistakes in both? Is $1+\cos\theta$ always greater than $1$? Is $xdA = (1+\cos\theta)\cos\theta\cdot rdrd\theta$?

İ understand the point that its not always greater than 1 but can you explain your second point, or maybe help me understand how to determine boundaries for r.

When you integrate over a region, you cannot plug in your boundaries in your integrand. It's the same mistake as saying $\int_0^3xdx= \int_0^33dx$

Oh i get your point, so since our region is between the r=1 and r=1+cosθ should i take x as the differences of x-values in our circle and curve?If not how can i change the variable x?
